# DHT22 Does not update

Tags: arduino-uno

Good evening :)

I am fairily new to coding the fabulous Arduino UNO. My project right now are consisting of reading Temperature from a DHT22 (AM2302) and writing to a 4-digit 7-segment display. I have got the display to work, but the system does not update the temperature at all. Just the first reading are displayed

```
#include <DHT.h>
  #include <TimerOne.h>
  #include <SevenSeg.h>

  #define DHTPIN 4    //Defines the temp-pin

  /* DHT22- Pin1 (left) - 5V/3.3V
  Pin2- DATA
    Connect a 10K res from pin1 to pin2
  Pin3 - NC
  Pin4 - GND
  */

  //#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11 
  #define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
  //#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)

  DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

  SevenSeg disp (13 ,2 ,3 ,8 ,5 ,6 ,7);
  //            (11, 7, 4, 2, 1, 10, 5)
  const int numOfDigits =4;
  int digitPins [ numOfDigits ]={9,10,11,12};  // uten transistorer
  //                            (12,9,8,6) Alle med 220 Ohm seriemotstand
  //int digitPins [ numOfDigits ]={12,11,10,9};  // med transistorer

  void setup () 
  {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("DHT22");

    disp . setCommonCathode();  // uten transistorer
    //disp . setActivePinState(HIGH,HIGH);  // med transistoere
    disp . setDigitPins ( numOfDigits , digitPins );

    Timer1.initialize(15);   // 0.015 sek
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(loop);
  }

  void loop() {

    dht.begin();

    delay(300);
    float t = dht.readTemperature();   

    disp.writeFloat(t);
    Serial.println(t);

  }
```

How do I get the Sensor to update regularly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving `dht.begin();` to `setup()`.

The DHTs are pretty slow and need some time (of the order of seconds!) between consecutive reads. In `dht.begin()` an internal timer is reset that is used in `readTemperature()` to ensure that reading data from the DHT is not attempted in shorter intervals than supported. By calling `dht.begin()` every 300 ms you're making this meachanism inoperative. You're supposed to call `dht.begin()` only once at start-up.

**Edit**: And please also remove the `Timer1` that calls `loop`. `loop` is already an infinite loop, so no good in calling it additionally from an interrupt...

Comment: Yaay, It worked!! And makes completely sense :D Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your loop method
The while loop will read the temperature, write to the display and write to the console.

```
void loop() {
  dht.begin();
  float t; 
  while(1)
  {
    t = dht.readTemperature();   
    disp.writeFloat(t);
    Serial.println(t);
  }
  delay(300);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer :D Buuut it did not do any difference

Comment: Do you get anything on the console?

Comment: @Gerben , I did get the first reading repeated over and over again